# Using jQuery to check if some radio buttons are checked and apply CSS block style

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to check if one of the following radio buttons is selected and am beginning to think that there must be a better way of achieving the same result using a different jQuery approach.

E.g:

```
if($("input[id='incRating_yes']:checked").val()) $('.question4').css('display','block');
if($("input[id='incRating_fro']:checked").val()) $('.question4').css('display','block');
if($("input[id='incRating_both']:checked").val()) $('.question4').css('display','block');
```

Any ideas?

Additional details:-

HTML:

```
<span class="clearfix">
<label>Do you want to allow users to add Interim Reviews?</label>
Yes <input type="radio" name="interimRev" id="interimRev_yes" value="y" <?php if($interimRev=='y') echo "checked";?>/>
No <input type="radio" name="interimRev" id="interimRev_no" value="n" <?php if($interimRev=='n') echo "checked";?>/>
</span>

<span class="question3" id="question3" style="display:none;">
<label>Include Rating?</label>
<p id="lbl_incRating_no"><input type="radio" name="incRating" id="incRating_no" value="n" <?php if($incRating=='n') echo "checked";?>/> No</p>
<p id="lbl_incRating_yes"><input type="radio" name="incRating" id="incRating_yes" value="y" <?php if($incRating=='y') echo "checked";?>/> Yes</p>
<p id="lbl_incRating_fro"><input type="radio" name="incRating" id="incRating_fro" value="fro" <?php if($incRating=='fro') echo "checked";?>/> Final Review Only</p>
<p id="lbl_incRating_both"><input type="radio" name="incRating" id="incRating_both" value="b" <?php if($incRating=='b') echo "checked";?>/> Both Interim and Final Reviews</p>
</span>
```

Depending on the radio selected from "Do you want to allow users to add Interim Reviews?", certain radio buttons will be displayed.

After Php validates the submission I need to be able to show the UI again and determine which radio buttons are checked, hence the jQuery code originally posted.

Comment: what does the markup look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might go for [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

eg

```
var element = $('selector');
if (element.is(':checked')) {
   element.css('display', 'block');
}
```

your solution might be

```
if ($('input#incRating_yes').is(':checked')
    || $('input#incRating_fro').is(':checked')
    || $('input#incRating_both').is(':checked')) {
    $('.question4').css('display', 'block');
}
```

maybe you will need to change `:checked` to `:selected`
furthermore: you should go for `#`-selectors if you use ids, due: ids must be unique!

Comment: Not sure if this will work in my situation as there are more radio buttons in addition to the ones above. But, a question before determines which radio buttons to display. So if I validated on `name`, I would end up checking the whole group.

Comment: could you include some demo-html, your question is not that clear to me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

```
$("input[id^='incRating_']:checked").length
```

and check whether it is 0 or not.

If you can give these checkbooxes a class name then you can use something like

```
$("input:radio.yourclassname:checked").length
```

Comment: Nice idea but as per my comment for Andreas.

Comment: If your checkboxes `id` starts with `incRating_` then the first method will do it for you.

Comment: change the `:checkbox` to `:radio` as according to the OP, they are radio buttons

Comment: Where is the answer left which used the OR method, i.e. if(incRating_yes is checked) or (incRating_fro is checked) or (incRating_both is checked) apply styles.

I can't find the answer and this was the solution I was looking for.